# MatLab: Line break between arguments of a function

Tags: matlab, whitespace

When writing a function with arguments in MatLab, can the arguments be separated by a line break in some way (similar to separation by whitespace characters such as `space` or `tab` being allowed)? An example is to change this code line

```
choice = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);
```

to these lines

```
choice = inputdlg(
  prompt,
  dlg_title,
  num_lines,
  defaultans
);
```

This particular syntax does not work, but it shows the idea that is possible in many other programming languages. Is it possible in MatLab as well?

Answer (score 2):

Long lines can be continued`...`

```
>> choice = inputdlg(prompt,...
dlg_title,...
num_lines,...
defaultans);
Undefined function or variable 'prompt'.

>>
```

however this is perhaps not an improvement.

Comment: This is the way to do it! It's definitely an improvement in function calls with lots of parameters or very long ones, like file locations.